# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined in setInterval function

Tags: javascript, angular, setinterval

So in the below code I'm pushing an object in the messages array after I receive  it from a websocket. After this I would like to call setInterval and add a minute to the minutesAgo property of the objects inside the messages array every 60 seconds.

Unfortunately I get an error `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined` inside the `getMinutesAgo()` function. I pushed the object into the messages array earlier, so I don't understand why `this.messages` is undefined. Does someone know why?

```
export class MovieChatComponent implements OnInit{

    fullName;
    title = 'Websocket Demo';
    url;
    ws;
    messages = [];
    movieChatElem;

    constructor(private movieChatService: MovieChatService){

    }

    ngOnInit(){
        this.fullName = localStorage.getItem('fullName');
        this.url = 'ws://localhost:3185';
        this.movieChatService.createObservableSocket(this.url)
            .subscribe(obj => {
                console.log(obj);
                this.messages.push(obj);
                console.log(this.messages);
                this.movieChatElem.scrollTop = this.movieChatElem.scrollHeight - this.movieChatElem.clientHeight;
                this.startTimeCalculations()
                },
                err => console.log(err),
                () => console.log('The observable stream, is complete'));
    }

    startTimeCalculations(){
        setInterval(this.getMinutesAgo,60000);
    }

    getMinutesAgo (){
        console.log('entered');
        console.log(this.messages);
        this.messages.forEach(function (msg) {
            msg.minutesAgo++;
            console.log('done');
            console.log(msg.minutesAgo);
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: You can do this: `setInterval(() => { this.getMinutesAgo(); }, 60000);`.

Comment: This is brilliant. Could you please explain shortly how it made a difference for this.messages (undefined versus actually a value)?

Comment: Oh wait. There is a link. Thank you very much.

Comment: You can also see the section "No separate this" in [this MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).